# How to watch a directory and `cp` file on change?

Tags: files, filesystem, cp

I'm building a little website generator, and I want to be able to watch some files. For example images, or js files. And then, when those files change, I'd like to copy them over to the site directory.

Can I do this in on the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to keep files in sync, [lsyncd](https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd) is the program of choice. You can install it via `sudo apt-get install lsyncd`. It's very extensible and can almost certainly handle your use case. However, if you want a simpler wrapper around the underlying `inotify` (the system call that tells programs when files change), you can use `inotifywait` or `inotifywatch` from the `inotify-tools` package.

Comment: Cool! Does lsyncd handle new file create, moving files into subdirectories, subdirectory creation?

Comment: I believe it handles all of those things.